# Best way to select from several LUTs? (Modelica)

Tags: simulation, lookup-tables, modelica, openmodelica

In our model of a physical system, we modify one flux value by a factor from a look-up table. The LUT itself is selected from a catalog of LUTs based on an integer index. We're currently loading the table data into CombiTable2D components. What is the correct way to select/define the correct LUT? If we have them all as named tables in one input data file, is there a way to pick an LUT based on it's tableName (the CombiTable parameter)? I've been playing with For loops in either equation or algorithm formats, but haven't found a syntax that works yet.

Thanks in advance for the thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

I think it only works with one table per file so you can have an array of tables, something like:

```
parameter Integer N = 3;
parameter String selectTable = "tab2";
Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D tableArray[N](
   each tableOnFile = true,
   fileName = {"file1", "file2", "file3"}, 
   tableName={"tab1", "tab2", "tab3"});
// use the tableArray
for i in 1:N loop
  // note that N and selectTable need to be known at compile 
  // time so that the if and the for loop can be expanded
  if (tableArray[i].tableName == selectTable)
  then 
   connect(tableArray[i].u1, u1);
   connect(tableArray[i].u2, u2);
   connect(tableArray[i].y, y);
  endif;
end for;
```